# Pass parameters from one method to another method of button.click

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, parameter-passing

I got  a main button function, where i parse the textbox text values, then I pass those values to an another method. 
After performing the first calculation, then i want to pass those parameters to another button function.

I want to assign  `int valueOF1, int valueOF2`to this method `public void testfunction(object sender, EventArgs ea)` from the main button.

How can i do this?? Thank you for your help.

This is the code:

```
private void b_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int valueOF1;
        int.TryParse(t_Offset1.Text, NumberStyles.Any,
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out valueOF1);

        int valueOF2;
        int.TryParse(t_Offset2.Text, NumberStyles.Any,
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out valueOF2);

        int pRows = PrimaryRadGridView.Rows.Count;
        int sRows = SecondaryRadGridView.Rows.Count;

        if (pRows == 1 && sRows == 1)
        {
            calculatePS(valueOF1, valueOF2);
        }


}

private void calculatePS(int valueOF1, int valueOF2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are using : P-S");
    // Do some calculation & go to the next function ///
    Button2.Enabled = true;
    Button2.Click += testfunction; // Here i want to pass the valueOF1 & valueOF2

}

public void testfunction(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you...!");
    Button2.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: testFunction is an EventHandler. Its signature cannot be changed to add your parameters. You could use a common function callable from calculatePS and from testFunction

Comment: [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.71).aspx) can be used I think. (dont know much about it)

Comment: @Steve : Could you explain to me, how can i use `common function callable from calculatePS and from testFunction`

Comment: The answer from Matthias could be good one for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `valueOF1` and `valueOF2` as class fields, so you can access them from different methods.

Here's how the code could look like:

```
int valueOF1 = 0;
int valueOF2 = 0;

private void b_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int.TryParse(t_Offset1.Text, NumberStyles.Any,
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out valueOF1);

    int.TryParse(t_Offset2.Text, NumberStyles.Any,
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out valueOF2);

    int pRows = PrimaryRadGridView.Rows.Count;
    int sRows = SecondaryRadGridView.Rows.Count;

    if (pRows == 1 && sRows == 1)
    {
        calculatePS();
    }
}

private void calculatePS()
{
    // ** you can use valueOF1 and valueOF2 here **

    MessageBox.Show("You are using : P-S");
    // Do some calculation & go to the next function ///
    Button2.Enabled = true;

    //probably no need to register the Button2.Click event handler
    //except when the form is created
    //
    //Button2.Click += testfunction; 
}

public void testfunction(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    // ** you can use valueOF1 and valueOF2 here as well **

    MessageBox.Show("you...!");
    Button2.Enabled = false;
}
```

***Additional Note:** `int.TryParse` returns a `bool` value that tells you whether the parse succeeded. In case the return is `false`, you may want to handle the parse error somehow instead of continuing with the normal flow.*

Comment: If no need to register the Button2.Click event handler,then how does the button know which function should call??

Comment: you can do `Button2.Click += testfunction;` once, when the form is created (for example, bind the event using the form designer). No need to reassign it every time `b_calculate` is clicked.

Comment: The problem, i have different calculation for different files, so each time, i'll assign a different function to this button. When i use `int valueOF1, int valueOF2` do i get the user entered value or 0?? (I know it sound silly but just want to know)

Comment: @linguini inside the `testfunction` handler you'd get the latest entered (and hopefully valid) values of `valueOF1` and `valueOF2`, because they are assigned inside the `b_calculate_Click` method

Comment: @linguini please check that the calls to `TryParse` returned `true`.

Comment: @linguini to simplify things, I removed the parameters of the `calculatePS` method, as they are no longer needed (the values are kept in the fields).

Comment: @linguini I just made a test and everything worked as expected. Do you still have the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19710/discussion-between-linguini-and-w0lf)

Answer (score 4):

Within your function calculatePS change the last line as follows

```
Button2.Click += new EventHandler(delegate 
{ 
  // within this delegate you can use your value0F1 and value0F2
  MessageBox.Show("you...!");
  Button2.Enabled = false;
});
```

Comment: &Matthias: How can i ref to the function, `testfunction;`?

Comment: If you're using the delegate, then you don't need the testfunction. The delegate is already the function. But hooking up new event handlers by += is not a nice solution and may lead to MemoryLeaks. Better remember your two values as private class members and call testfunction on Button2.Click always.